# Confused by simplification of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I have two operators defined as:

$$ \hat{A} \psi_n(x) = \sqrt{n} \psi_{n-1}(x), $$

$$ \hat{A}^+ \psi_{n-1}(x) = \sqrt{n} \psi_n(x). $$

And then I have this summation with its simplification:

$$ \hat{A} \hat{A} +\hat{A}^+\hat{A}^+ + \hat{A}^+\hat{A} + \hat{A}\hat{A}^+ $$

simplifies to
$$ \hat{A}^+\hat{A} + \hat{A}\hat{A}^+.$$

I don't understand why the first two terms cancel out, its confusing me. I am still new to operators so my brain can't quite think correctly with them yet.

Hope some one can explain what is going on here and why they cancel out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two terms cannot cancel each other, I think, this equation is meant in the sense of action on a state with definite number of particles $\psi_n$.

The operator $\hat{A}^{+} \hat{A}^{+}$ increases the occupation number by 2 -  maps $\psi_n$ to $\psi_{n+2}$, whereas $\hat{A} \hat{A}$ maps $\psi_n$ to $\psi_{n-2}$.

Being sandwiched by any state $\psi_n = | n \rangle$ first two terms give zero:
$$
\langle n | \hat{A}^{+} \hat{A}^{+} | n \rangle = 
\langle n | \hat{A} \hat{A} | n \rangle = 0
$$
Because $\langle m | n \rangle \sim \delta_{mn}$, states with different occupation numbers are **orthogonal** to each other.

These combinations vanish in the expectation values, but are not equal as operators.

Comment: I've not yet learn this bra-ket notation. But if the first maps +2 and the other -2 why is it wrong to say they cancel out ?

Comment: They cancel in the expectation value, because after the apllication of them, you will have $\sim \langle n |n + 2 \rangle$, $\sim \langle n |n - 2 \rangle$ which are both zero due to the orthogonality of states with different occupation numbers.

Comment: Ohh i see it now, thanks :)